# How to avoid declaring sampler outside of statement?

Tags: shader, fragment-shader

How can I avoid having to declare the sampler outside of the if statement in this shader code sample?

```
let sample = textureSample(r_texture, r_sampler, in.tex_coords);
if in.use_texture {
    return sample * in.color;
} else {
    return in.color;
}
```

This came up as an answer to another of my [questions](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/13682/conditionally-sample-from-texture-in-shader/13683#13683), and it was suggested that the sampler needed to be declared here due to uniform control flow, but that it could be avoided.

How to avoid it?

Comment: This more of avoiding calling the textureSample function outside an if statement then declaring it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Background

In order to support [mipmapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mipmap), the texture sampling system needs to know what scale the texture is being displayed at. In order to determine that scale automatically, the *derivatives* (or “gradient”) of the texture coordinates are used. The way GPUs calculate derivatives is by comparing the results of the calculations performed in one fragment to adjacent fragments.

The reason you can't put `textureSample` inside of `if` is because it is possible that the `if` takes different branches on different pixels, and so the derivative won't exist. “Uniform control flow” means “all fragments are guaranteed to execute this code”.

### Possible solutions

- If `r_texture` has no mipmaps, or if `r_sampler` is configured to prevent using them, then you don't need to select a mipmap level. Use `textureSampleLevel(r_texture, r_sampler, in.tex_coords, 0.0)` — the additional argument is the mipmap level, and 0 means the full-resolution texture, which is all you want in this case.
- If you do wish to use mipmaps, then you can compute the relevant derivatives outside of the `if`, and use them inside:

  ```
  let ddx = dpdx(in.tex_coords);
  let ddy = dpdy(in.tex_coords);
  if in.use_texture {
      let sample = textureSampleGrad(r_texture, r_sampler, in.tex_coords, ddx, ddy);
      return sample * in.color;
  } else {
      return in.color;
  }
  ```

  This is basically doing what `textureSample` would do implicitly, but moving just the parts that can't be in the `if` outside.

### Language notes

The code in this answer is [WGSL](https://www.w3.org/TR/WGSL/). Equivalent functions in GLSL:

| WGSL | GLSL |
| --- | --- |
| textureSample() | texture() |
| textureSampleGrad() | textureGrad() |
| dpdx() | dFdx() |
| dpdy() | dFdy() |

Also, [here's another introduction to the same concepts from the Khronos OpenGL wiki (which uses GLSL)](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Sampler_(GLSL)#Non-uniform_flow_control).

Comment: Thanks, that was very insightful. FWIW, I found that the mipmap level in `textureSampleLevel()` needs to be specified as a float.